# PostgreSQL compare data across different servers

Tags: sql, postgresql

I've one problem regarding manage information from two different Postgres servers.

- In the one server I've one table `a` containing `id bigserial` and `phone varchar(200)`
- On the other server I've table `b` that contains `id bigserial` and `tell varchar(200)`

Is there a way that I can compare witch rows from table `a` are present in the rows of table `b`, comparing by `phone` = `tell`?

Comment: Thank you, it might help, but I've no access to the management of the servers, and this dblink function is not installed. After I manage to install it, I'll be able to tell you if this is helpful for me. :)

Comment: Glad your up and running :-) Please consider upvoting (and accepting) both the answer below, and the answer on the linked post to help other users in the future.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [dblink](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/dblink.html) to fetch data from remote server. Once you have a cursor open you can treat data from `dblink_fetch` as data returned from local table and just outer join it with the local table. If there are many rows in the remote table you might want to use pl/pgSQL to fetch it in parts.